# Unable to download files from site via Powershell. Issue appears related to TLS 1.2

Tags: powershell, tls1.2

Two days ago a trusty inherited powershell script started failing with a

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." error.

With no Powershell experts in house, I went to Googling, and the issue appears to be that Powershell defaults to TLS 1.0.  I confirmed using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ that the site supports 1.2, but not 1.0 now.  Perfect, there are tonnes of sites that mention to insert:
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 into the code.  However, no matter how I try to implement that line of code; it still fails with the same error.  I tried writing a less complex Powershell script from scratch, but the error persists with the fix.

The original code:

```
#$storageDir = "E:\Folder"<br>
#$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient<br>
#$url = "https://jibber.website.com/DBBackup.jsp?userName=BOB&password=l33t"<br>
#$sb = new-object System.Text.StringBuilder<br>
#$file = "$storageDir\backup.zip"<br>
#wget $url -OutFile $file<br>

#$file = (new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadString($url)<br>
#echo "I have the link ($url)"<br>
#echo "going to download"<br>
#$to = "$storageDir\backup.zip"<br>
#$target = "$storageDir\backup"<br>
#$webclient.DownloadFile($file,$to)<br>
New-Item E:\folder\backup -type directory<br>
$downloadRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing –Uri  'https://jibber.website.com/DBBackup.jsp?userName=BOB&password=l33t'<br> 
$url =  $downloadRequest.Links<br>
(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url.href,'E:\folder\backup\backup.zip');
```

No matter where or how I try to insert:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

It continues to fail.  I'm sure I'm missing something stupid, but how and where am I supposed to implement that into the code above?

PS: I'm completely open to a different script for downloading and placing the file.  Just bare in mind the site uses a "Database backup link: Here. This link will be up for 1 week." link for getting the file.

EDIT: So with some help, we've determined the issue is specifically occurring on the server.  So the script works fine with the [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12" call on other machines, BUT not on the server. The theory is that powershell can't seem to access .netframework properly...but I've yet to resolve the issue.

Comment: when i set this >>> `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'tls12, tls11, tls'` <<< at the top of any script that needs tls1.2, it works. you can also set it in your various powershell profiles, but that means you may forget it when needed.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey That's what my understanding was.  However, putting that at the beginning of the code up above seems to have no effect.

Comment: can you run that in a new console without any errors? i suspect that you don't have access to the needed dotnet version ... but i don't know how to test that. [*blush*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I think you're right.  A coworker of mine tackled  it solely on his local machine and got it working.  I made small tweaks for file locations and it works fine on my local machine.  Whatever the issue, it's when it's being run on the server (I should have done more testing locally - head to desk).  I'm trying the whole turning Windows Feature On thing and such (for 4.5, but am still stuck.  Either way, it definitely smells like a .net Framework issue now.  I'll update hopefully when I get it working on the server.

Comment: i wish you the best of good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: This might help https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-gallery-tls-support/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this:

```
if ( -not ("TrustAllCertsPolicy" -as [type])) {
Add-Type @"
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
public bool CheckValidationResult(
ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) { return true; }
}
"@
}
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'
```

Comment: Alright, pasted it "as is" just to test and it throws a "White space is not allowed before the string terminator".  I removed that preceding spaces which eliminated the error.  I then tried added that to the beginning of the code, but the issue persists.  Was your snip to go somewhere else other than the beginning?

Comment: It has to be declared before performing a web request. Usually it does the job for any SSL/TLS isues i have...check updated code above. maybe it will help. put it on top of your script.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to check wheter TLS protocols are supported on both sides, both client and the website.
There's an excellent and free(!) tool for this: https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/
You can run IISCrypto on your machine and see what is supported. It can also apply settings.

Probably you're not in control of 'the other side'. On the same page, you can enter the url of the 'other side'. You will be redirected to https://SSLlabs.com, that site will generate a report. Takes a couple of minutes, but then you can easily see what they support.